# CakeDC search plugin - check if flag is set

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I'm using the cakeDC search plugin in my cake app (2.2). As part of a basic search form I want to ensure only live records are returned (live being a flag in the database - a tinyint, 0 for deleted, 1 for live).

I've tried doing this in my controller:

```
$isLive = array('live' => '1');
$this->passedArgs = set::merge($this->passedArgs, $isLive);
```

But it didnt work...

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691961/cakedc-search-plugin-use-pb) but the answer didnt really help. Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I missed the filterArgs in the model:

```
public $filterArgs = array(
    'username' => array('type' => 'like'),
    'company' => array('type' => 'like'),
    'live' => array('type' => 'value')
);
```

Hopefully this will help someone